# How to retrieve month wise data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table called Transaction:

[image]

Now I have to Show monthly Balance, so

```
Output will be:
Month   Balance
January 1600
February 800
```

That means, I have to consider previous Month's Debit and Credit for current month calculation also.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why would January (of what year?) balance be 1600? Does time somehow begin in January of 2019? For just the 2 accounts you show or for every account in this system no matter who uses it? And why do you show a single value per month and not a balance per account? What will happen next year - do you want Jan 2019 to be combined with Jan 2020? Probably not - so you to stop and think about your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
SELECT ABS((SUM(CREDIT) -SUM(DEBIT))) AS BALANCE, 
CASE 
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =1 THEN 'JANUARY'
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =2 THEN 'FEBRUARY'
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =3 THEN 'MARCH'
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =4 THEN 'APRIL'
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =5 THEN 'MAY'
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =6 THEN 'JUNE'
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =7 THEN 'JULY'
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =8 THEN 'AUGUST'
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =9 THEN 'SEPTEMBER'
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =10 THEN 'OCTOBER'
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =11 THEN 'NOVEMBER'
WHEN MONTH(DATE) =12 THEN 'DECEMBER'
ELSE
'N/A'
END
AS MONTH  FROM TEMP_TABLE_001
GROUP BY MONTH(DATE)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for aggregation and a cumulative sum.  Date operations vary by data

```
select year(date), month(date),
       sum(credit - debit) as month_change,
       sum(sum(credit - debit)) over (order by min(date)) as month_balance
from transaction
group by year(date), month(date)
order by year(date), month(date);
```

I've used `year()` and `month()` as typical date functions -- although these are not standard SQL, they are easily understood and equivalent functions are available in any database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

`SELECT MONTH(Date) AS Month, SUM(Debit), SUM(Credit)
FROM <Transaction>`

Hope this will help.